# When to use param and rosparam on launch file?

Tags: ros, parameter, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For param example:

```
 <launch>
   <!-- send table urdf to param server -->
   <param name="table_description" command="$(find      xacro)/xacro.py $(find gazebo_worlds)/objects/table.urdf.xacro" />
 
   <!-- push table_description to factory and spawn robot in      gazebo -->
   <node name="spawn_table" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"      args="-urdf -param table_description -z 0.01 -model table_model"      respawn="false" output="screen" />
 </launch>
```

For rosparam example:

```
 <launch>
   <node name="fake_localizaton" type="fake_localization"      pkg="fake_localization">
     <rosparam>
       odom_frame_id: odom_combined
       base_frame_id: base_footprint
     </rosparam>
   </node>
 </launch>
```

What's their difference?

What's the case of using them?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37916/when-to-use-param-and-rosparam-on-launch-file?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the main difference is that `<param>` may be used to set a single command on the ROS parameter server, while `<rosparam>` can be used to evaluate groups of parameters.

So, in the cases above, `<param>` is setting a *single* parameter, and that parameter is an entire URDF file.  The `<rosparam>` tag is reading in the [rosparam yaml format](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam#YAML_Format) from within the launch file.

The value set by the `<param>` tag may only be a `string, int, bool`, or `double`, which may be set through the xml attribute `value`, or by reading in from a text file, bin file, or the output of a command line command.

The value set by the `<rosparam>` tag is most commonly a batch of related parameters, read in from a YAML file (or from the output of [rosparam dump](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam#rosparam_dump)).  You can think of it as a programmatic way to access the functionality of [rosparam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam) from a launch file.  A good example of this in practice is the `move_base` related nodes, where there are many, many parameters to be set, it's less cumbersome to just use the YAML format.

For more information on all of these topics, I would consult the following:

- [roslaunch xml syntax](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML)
- [The roslaunch param tag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/param)
- [The roslaunch rosparam tag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/rosparam)
- [The rosparam command](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam)

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 33

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-07-02**:
This information has been added here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Patterns/Parameterization#Static_Parameters (feel free to edit)